# Quadratic Form $f\left(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n\right)=\sum _{i=1}^m \left(a_{i 1}x_1+\cdots +a_{i n}x_n\right)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Quadratic Form $f\left(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n\right)=\sum _{i=1}^m \left(a_{i 1}x_1+\cdots +a_{i n}x_n\right)^2$,

i) write the corresponding matrix;

ii) when $a_{\text{ij}}$ are all real numbers, gives the condition, when the quadratic form is positive.

- i)

\begin{align*}\left|\begin{array}{cccc} \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}^2 & \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}a_{i 2} & \cdots  & \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}a_{i n} \\ \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}a_{i 2} & \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}^2 & \cdots  & \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 2}a_{i n} \\ \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots  \\ \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i 1}a_{i n} & \cdots  & \cdots  & \sum _{i=1}^n a_{i n}^2 \\\end{array}\right|\end{align*}

Is it right?

- ii)

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Define
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} &\cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} &\cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} &   a_{n2} &\cdots & a_{nn} \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
and 
$$
X^t=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)
$$
Then $f=(A\cdot X)\cdot(A\cdot X)=X\cdot (A^tA\cdot X)=X^t\cdot(A^tA)\cdot X=||A\cdot X||^2$.